# Unable to load DLL Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x86.dll in Entityframework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, webforms, entity-framework-core, nuget

I have web-form project (project A) which has reference to another class library project (Project B) which I use for Data Access Layer, I installed EntityFramework 3.1.15 in both projects A & B,  now I got a run-time error in  `db.SaveChanges();` error says:

**Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x86.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)**

Project B is using .NETFramework 4.7.2, and Project A was .NETFramework 4.5 & later I changed it to .NETFramework 4.7.2. but I got same error.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check  (use the nuget tool) if SqlClient is installed in  the web project.

Comment: Take a look a the below URL on how to resolve it, good luck.

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/727

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I already added SqlClient to my class library & the web forms projects but the error was still shown and the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x86.dll was not shown in the Bin folder of the web form project. Later I added Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x86.dll as reference manually not by using Nuget & the error has gone. Thank you

Comment: Wow, did they screw this one up. Lots of runtime errors with missing assemblies with this one. Apparently, referencing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient isn't enough. If you use a project that happens to use that, you MUST ALSO directly reference this weird SNI assembly package in the executable project, too. Seems to break the whole concept of using Nuget.  But in Nuget, the project says "Internal implementation package not meant for direct consumption. Please do not reference directly." https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the error I had to reference **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI** nuget in my executable project where my database connection project has already **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** referenced.

Hope this helps.